# How to insert proper punctuation in string

Tags: python

I have removed all the punctuation from a string sentence to manipulate the order of words. Then I am to insert the punctuation back to the original position. What do I do? Do I find the position index of the original punctuation and add it back in manipulated string?

For example:

- Original:
  "Hello. My name is John Smith."
- Manipulated:
  "elloh my amen is ohnj ithms"
- Goal:
  "elloh. my amen is ohnj ithms."

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this would be to use the insert method. However, this method only works for lists, so you would have to convert the strings to lists.

```
original = 'Hello. My name is John Smith.'
manipulated = "elloh my amen is ohnj ithms"
manipulated = list(manipulated)
for i in range(len(original)):
    if original[i] in [".","!","?",":",";"]: # add more if needed
        manipulated.insert(i,original[i])
print("".join(manipulated))
```

This program will give your desired output of "elloh. my amen is ohnj ithms."

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. but what if there are different punctuation in the same string? How do I make sure the correct punctuation would be inserted in the right place for different ones? For example, what if the punctuation after Hello is "!'?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the feedback. I have modified the program to answer your question better.

Comment: What if the manipulated string got longer? how do I shift the punctuation to the correct spot? For example, "the original phrase is 'Can you speak Spanish?' and the goal is " Ellohay! Ancay ouyay eakspay Anishsp?". Such as the position is the same after string got longer! Thank you!!

Comment: If the original phrase is only "Can you speak Spanish?",  how will it turn into "Ellohay! Ancay ouyay eakspay Anishsp?"?

Comment: it is a pig latin. and I have wrote functions that rearranged the characters of the words and added 'ay' or 'way' to the end depending on the first character in vowel or not. But I don't know how to insert the punctuation back into the sentences after the manipulation.